# S3 bucket changing the file name to content-type

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using module **aws-s3** from react code to upload the file on s3 bucket. File upload works fine but as soon as it is upload, name is converted into something look like this for xlsx :
https://5UcGpAsjx8AjQa4eUUGKtW.vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

which is content type for xlsx file but should not automatically converted like this

Any solution ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the code where you do the upload? It's not possible for s3 to save file with a different key than what you specify!

Comment: here is my codes  Config :{
        bucketName:name,
        region: region,
        dirName: dirName,
        accessKeyId: id,
        secretAccessKey:key
    },         S3Client.uploadFile(this.state.uploadFile)

Comment: Where are you specifying the file to upload? Please edit your question and show the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the latest version of AWS-s3. When we moved to previous version, error got resolved.

Thanks for the help :)